# Application spyder launch may have produced errors

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, launch

I am trying to start Spyder from Anaconda on a Mac, but get the error below. As a result, Spyder does not launch. The same error arises if I try to launch Spyder from the terminal.

Any ideas on the cause of the error and/or how to solve it? There have been similar questions in the past but the errors were different, that's why I am reposting.

Versions:
Spyder - 3.2.8
Anaconda - 1.8.3
Python - 3.6.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 7, in 
from spyder.app.start import main
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 27, in 
from spyder.config.main import CONF
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/config/main.py", line 22, in 
from spyder.config.user import UserConfig
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/config/user.py", line 26, in 
from spyder.utils.programs import check_version
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/programs.py", line 18, in 
import subprocess
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in 
import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Py_set_inheritable_async_safe
Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might have to downgrad python to 3.6.4.

or:

run this command:

```
conda update python python.app
```

Comment: python.app seemed to be already updated. However, downgrading Python to v 3.6.4 worked. Thank you very much!!